# django dynamic translate on AppEngine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, internationalization, translation, djangoappengine

I need dynamic translation in django on AppEngine.

I found nice django modul for dynamic translations: django-rosetta, but it open files (django.po...) and it is not allowed on AppEngine.

Exist some other translate modul where is compatibile (or with small fix) with AppEngine?

Thanks. Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [rosettaappengine Github project](https://github.com/benglynn/rosettappengine) that should help you to get django-rosetta to work in GAE. The process seems a bit complicated though.